# split string list into sublist in python

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

Looking for a way to split the following string list into sublist and print using a for loop.

```
[[[u'Book1', None, u'Thriller', u'John C', u'07/12/2012'],
[u'Book2', u'1', u'Action', u'Tom B', u'07/12/2012'],
[u'Book3', None, u'Romance', u'Angie P', u'07/12/2012'],
[u'Book4', None, u'Comedy', u'Tracy N', u'07/12/2012'],
[u'Book5', None, u'Drama', u'Kumar P', u'07/12/2012'],
[u'Book6', None, u'Action&Drama', u'Ben J', u'07/12/2012']]]
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: What condition do you want to use to split it?

Comment: based on [u'Book1', None, u'Thriller', u'John C', u'07/12/2012']

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You should post what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague! If I understood your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```
a = [[[u'Book1', None, u'Thriller', u'John C', u'07/12/2012'], [u'Book2', u'1', u'Action', u'Tom B', u'07/12/2012'], [u'Book3', None, u'Romance', u'Angie P', u'07/12/2012'], [u'Book4', None, u'Comedy', u'Tracy N', u'07/12/2012'], [u'Book5', None, u'Drama', u'Kumar P', u'07/12/2012'], [u'Book6', None, u'Action&Drama', u'Ben J', u'07/12/2012']]]
for v in a[0]:
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
def testString():
    input = [[
    [u'Book1', None, u'Thriller', u'John C', u'07/12/2012'],
    [u'Book2', u'1', u'Action', u'Tom B', u'07/12/2012'],
    [u'Book3', None, u'Romance', u'Angie P', u'07/12/2012'],
    [u'Book4', None, u'Comedy', u'Tracy N', u'07/12/2012'],
    [u'Book5', None, u'Drama', u'Kumar P', u'07/12/2012'],
    [u'Book6', None, u'Action&Drama', u'Ben J', u'07/12/2012']
    ]]
    for subarray in input[0]:
        print (subarray)
```

This is the output

```
['Book1', None, 'Thriller', 'John C', '07/12/2012']
['Book2', '1', 'Action', 'Tom B', '07/12/2012']
['Book3', None, 'Romance', 'Angie P', '07/12/2012']
['Book4', None, 'Comedy', 'Tracy N', '07/12/2012']
['Book5', None, 'Drama', 'Kumar P', '07/12/2012']
['Book6', None, 'Action&Drama', 'Ben J', '07/12/2012']
```